# Find matrix of linear transformation $\mathcal{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let linear transformation is defined as

$\mathcal{A}(1,1,1)=(1,0,0)$

$\mathcal{A}(1,-1,0)=(1,1,1)$

$\mathcal{A}(1,0,1)=(1,1,1)$

Find matrix of $\mathcal{A}$ and inverse (not in matrix representation, if exists).

Attempt:

Transformation $\mathcal{A}$ can be represented as $\mathcal{A}:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ which can be represented by $\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{P_2}\rightarrow \mathcal{P_2}$ where $\mathcal{P_2}$ is the space of polynomials $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$.

$\mathcal{A}(1,1,1)=(1,0,0)\Rightarrow A        \begin{bmatrix}
        a  \\
        b  \\
        c  \\
        \end{bmatrix}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha \\
        0   \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

How to find matrix of $\mathcal{A}$?

Is this approach (with polynomial vector space) correct?

Comment: What does "not in matrix representation" means?

Comment: With respect to which basis do you want to find the matrix representation?

Comment: @Antonios-Alexandros Robotis , In standard basis.

Comment: @Shoutre, General representation, with domain and co-domain.

Comment: Can you find the matrix with respect to the basis $(1,1,1), (1,-1,0), (1,0,1)$?

Comment: Just take a look at the right hand side of the two last relations, and you can immediately tell if the inverse exists, or not !!

Comment: I have figured out how to find matrix $A$, but it requires solving linear system of $9$ equations with $9$ variables. Is there a shorter method?

Comment: In this case the system is simple. And, in general, there are not simpler methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

we have:
$$
A \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow \begin {cases}
a_1+b_1+c_1=1\\
a_2+b_2+c_2=0\\
a_3+b_3+c_3=0\\
\end {cases}
$$

$$
A \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow \begin {cases}
a_1-b_1=1\\
a_2-b_2=1\\
a_3-b_3=1\\
\end {cases}
$$

$$
A \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow \begin {cases}
a_1+c_1=1\\
a_2+c_2=1\\
a_3+c_3=1\\
\end {cases}
$$

Find $b_i=1+a_i$ and $c_i=1-a_i$ from the last two systems, so that $b_i+c_i=2$, and substitute in the first system. You find:

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&2\\
-2&-1&3\\
-2&-1&3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that clearly is not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Notice that if you call
$$ e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix} , \quad  e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix} , \quad  e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}  $$
We have that
$$ e_1 + e_2 - e_3 =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$  e_1 -  e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ - e_1 -e_2 + 2 e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let S be the matrix for $\mathcal{A}$.

Then $S\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&-1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$,

so $S=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&-1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\1&0&-1\\-1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&1\\0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Notice that $\mathcal{A}(1,-1,0)=\mathcal{A}(1,0,1)$, so $\mathcal{A}$ is not invertible

(and S is not invertible since it has two identical rows).